# Best Gearing for a very fit but on his way out 52 year old

Tags: gears, fitness

Firstly, I'm no beginner.
I've just bought a so called good bike from a major retailer.  Why would a "good" bike come with "beginner" gears?  Chainring 50-34 with 10 speed cassette 12-28.  I enjoy terrain that is similar to turbo training.  That is, get into a rhythm and fight to maintain it for as long as possible, changing gear one tooth to maintain cadence on slight up hills or into wind.  I will never opt for up and down big hills.  Not my idea of fun!  I enjoy hitting high speed and maintaining that....  But at 52 I'm not getting any stronger with time.  I'm thinking of switching to 12-25 just because it has more gears in the middle range.  but I now probably need a 48 on the front so that the ratio 3 +/- 0.3 is in the exact middle.  Can I get a 12-21?  What's the point of the smaller chainring?  All gears are duplicated except those at end of range which I will never use?  Why not remove and decrease weight?

Comment: There are plenty of options to choose gearing based on your riding style and terrain. If you've got the option  to only ride on almost flat roads the default gears are unlikely to suit you, as most people buying a bike don't have this option. But if you're not climbing hills, saving weight don't make much difference.

Comment: Because most of bike buyers these days are beginners. Before the current road bike boom, most road bikes went to people who raced, these days they go to commuters who LARP racers.

Comment: Also, a modern 11-25 is basically 8-speed 12-21 with one useless extra gear at top and two at low end.

Comment: @ChrisH - even if you were climbing hills, the weight of the crankset, derailleurs and cassette are basically all within the normal variation of a person on a day to day basis. A RD is say, 200-300 g, FD about 100 g, cassette about another 250-400 g and crankset 700-1000g. So, you're looking at roughly 1.25 kg to 1.8 kg, which is well within the 1-5 lbs that most people fluctuate around on a daily basis. So, I don't think saving weight is significant here, especially with say an average adult (who is probably, what, close to 70 kg?)

Comment: @Batman as an above average weight adult who just bought a bike with triple chainrings (and a steel frame) I can only agree. I try to understand the lightweight viewpoint but don't always succeed

Comment: Weight optimization isn't a means to accomplish something, but a goal in itself.

Comment: Why do you now probably need a 48 on the front?

Comment: The OP obviously knows his way around bikes and gearing and weights and knows what he wants. In that context, I am really struggling to see a question here.

Comment: The bikes stock and sell bikes configured to what most customers want. What you are asking for is very specific and not a common sale, so its uneconomic to have such a bike in stock. Its trivial to customize a bike for a customer such as yourself at sales time, so they take a stock bike, swap a cassette  and chain ring, and bingo. Real question is why did the shop not do this for you?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Sheldon Brown's Gear Calculator](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gear-calc.html) whenever I'm looking into gear ratios. For someone who doesn't ride any big hills I would think that 50/34 - 12/28 would be absolutely ideal. You could go 1x and get 98% of a 50/34 with a 44+10/42. See [SRAMs pocket guide](https://www.sram.com/sites/all/themes/sram_2011/st_road/_pdfs/sram-1x-and-2x/SRAM_1x_Digital_Guide_EN.pdf)

50-12 tops out at about 33mph definitely not something that mortals can sustain for very long on a flat road.

Comment: More important than highest gear is straight chainline for the gears you actually use.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't ride big hills then 53/39 (or 53/42) and 12-25 is the best for you.

(I am 51 yo.o and because of the big hills I had to switch from 53/42 12-25 and 53/39 12-25 to 50/34 and 12-25, even 12-27 for the very long big hills and long tours). Now in a region without big hills I will likely switch back to 53/39 and 12-25.)